# not able to start application because of special character in bat

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I am trying to start a exe from batch file but not able to start exe ...

Here is bat

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files\Marketmaker\Marketmaker CFD-FX Français\MM5\iidownloader.exe"
@pause
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `===` sequence is not part of the batch file, right?

Comment: no, sorry ===== is not part of batch

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the short name:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files\Marketmaker\Market~1\MM5\iidownloader.exe"
@pause
```

To check the correct short name, open a dos prompt and type:

```
dir /x "C:\Program Files\Marketmaker"
```

Comment: it is starting iidownloader.exe in command prompt(like a directory) .... not the application